# Number of $\alpha\in\Bbb{F}_{27}$ such that $|A_{\alpha}|=26$ equals $12$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

**Question:** Let $\Bbb{F}_{27}$ denote the finite field of size $27$. For each $\alpha\in\Bbb{F}_{27},$ we define
$$A_{\alpha}=\{1,1+\alpha,1+\alpha+\alpha^2,1+\alpha+\alpha^2+\alpha^3,\dots\}.$$
Then show that number of $\alpha\in\Bbb{F}_{27}$ such that $|A_{\alpha}|=26$ equals $12$.

What I could conclude is,

$0\in A_{\alpha}$ if and only if $ \alpha\neq0$.

Then I thought that, $|A_{\alpha}|=26$ implies $A_{\alpha}=\Bbb{F}_{27}^*$, but I am not sure. Then some guess what I was making from the fact $\phi(26)=12$, but no progress. Help me with this, because I not getting any clue from the structure of $A_{\alpha}$.

Comment: Hint: unless $\alpha=1$, $A_\alpha=\left\{\frac{\alpha^n-1}{\alpha-1}\right\}_{n=1,2,3,\ldots}$. So $|A_\alpha|$ is the number of distinct powers of $\alpha$. Now go [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_(finite_field)).

Comment: Sorry, how is $|A_{\alpha}|$ is the number of distinct powers of $\alpha$?

Comment: Because $\alpha^m=\alpha^n$ if and only if $\frac{\alpha^m-1}{\alpha-1}=\frac{\alpha^n-1}{\alpha-1}$.

Comment: Yes, I got it.  Thank you.

Comment: For $\alpha \in F$, where $F$ is a general finite field, $|A_{\alpha}|$ is the characteristic of $F$ if $\alpha=1$, $1$ if $\alpha=0$, and the order of $\alpha$ in $F^{\times}$ otherwise.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information.

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator{ord}{ord}$
For any element $a\in\mathbb{F}_{27}^*$ denote the order of element $a$ in the multiplicative group $a\in\mathbb{F}_{27}^*$ as $\ord a$. We will prove that for all $\alpha\neq 1$ we have $|A_{\alpha}|=\ord\alpha$. Indeed, note that
$$
|A_{\alpha}|=|(1-\alpha)\cdot A_{\alpha}|=|\{(1-\alpha)\cdot(1+\alpha+\ldots+\alpha^k)\mid k\geq 0\}|=
\\
=|\{1-\alpha^{k+1}\mid k\geq 0\}|=|\{\alpha^m\mid m\geq 1\}|=\ord\alpha.
$$

Therefore, you just need to find the number of elements of $a\in\mathbb{F}_{27}^*$ of order 26, which is exactly $\varphi(26)=12$, as you have mentioned in the question.

*Note 1.* For $\alpha=1$ we have $|A_1|=3$.

*Note 2.* Here, $c\cdot A$ means $c\cdot A=\{c\cdot a\mid a\in A\}$.

Comment: In prove of $|A_{\alpha}|=|(1-\alpha)\cdot A_{\alpha}$, what if, $(1-\alpha)(1+\alpha+\dots+\alpha^i)=(1-\alpha)(1+\alpha+\dots+\alpha^j)$ for some $i\neq j$.

Comment: Ok, I got it, thanks.

Comment: Note 1 is true because the field $\mathbb{F}_{27}$ has characteristic $3$.